# Cannot position background image of :before element correctly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve frosted glass effect as described here: https://css-tricks.com/frosting-glass-css-filters/. In order to do this, I need to add `:before` element with the same background and apply blur effect.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="root">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Ok hello</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.root {
  background: url('http://666a658c624a3c03a6b2-25cda059d975d2f318c03e90bcf17c40.r92.cf1.rackcdn.com/unsplash_527bf56961712_1.JPG') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 400px;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: red;
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}

.content:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;

  background: url('http://666a658c624a3c03a6b2-25cda059d975d2f318c03e90bcf17c40.r92.cf1.rackcdn.com/unsplash_527bf56961712_1.JPG') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.5;
  /* -webkit-filter: blur(5px); */
}
```

Here's the pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKgbKR

I can't seem to position the background of `:before` element correctly. It is always shifted vertically. I tried playing with translation of this element, adjust the background, but to no avail. The problem can be easily noticed in the right part of the image, especially if you try resizing the resulting document vertically.

I am an absolute beginner in CSS, so I'm out of ideas. Your help will be appreciated.

---

**EDIT:** I think I should clarify my requirements. I need to keep the `content` block centered vertically regardless of window size changes. The image should remain centered and cover the background. The content never changes.

Answer (score 0):

This might not show correctly on the snippet box, test it on your site and lmk

```css
.root {
  background: url('http://666a658c624a3c03a6b2-25cda059d975d2f318c03e90bcf17c40.r92.cf1.rackcdn.com/unsplash_527bf56961712_1.JPG') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 600px;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: red;
}
.content:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url('http://666a658c624a3c03a6b2-25cda059d975d2f318c03e90bcf17c40.r92.cf1.rackcdn.com/unsplash_527bf56961712_1.JPG') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Ok hello</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your snippet, vertical positioning is correct, but if I resize browser window horizontally, the positioning becomes incorrect again.

Comment: it wont, coz the height is set to 600px. you will have to change height based on your requirement or check the height using Jquery and adjust the height

Comment: My requirement is to keep the `content` block centered vertically regardless of window size changes. The image should remain centered and cover the background. The content never changes, so I don't really see the need to calculate height in code. Or is it the only way to achieve what I want?